# Is there an upper limit to the number of zombie processes you can have?

Tags: process, kill, limit, hp-ux, zombie-process

I used to work with an HP-UX system and the old admin told me there is an upper limit on the number of zombie processes you can have on the system, I believe 1024.

- Is this a hard fact ceiling?  I think you could have any number of zombies just as if you can have any number of processes...?
- Is it different value from distro to distro?
- What occurs if we hit the upper limit and try to create another zombie?

Comment: According to [this blog article](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/7/Dr.-Frankenlinux-or-how-to-create-zombie-processes/) the only limit on Linux is the number of PIDs, which only incidentally affects zombies.

Comment: Both answers below mention `ulimit -u`. I was confused for a while as `man ulimit` got me a C routine with no mention of `-u`. The mentioned ulimit is in fact a built-in bash tool and it is described in the bash manpage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have HP-UX available to me, and I've never been a big HP-UX fan.

It appears that on Linux, a per-process or maybe per-user limit on how many child processes exists. You can see it with the `limit` Zsh built-in (seems to be analogous to `ulimit -u` in bash):

```
1002 % limit
cputime         unlimited
filesize        unlimited
datasize        unlimited
stacksize       8MB
coredumpsize    0kB
memoryuse       unlimited
maxproc         16136
  ...
```

That's on an Arch linux laptop.

I wrote a little program to test that limit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile int sigchld_cnt = 0;

voida
sigchld_hdlr(int signo)
{
        ++sigchld_cnt;
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
        int looping = 1;
        int child_cnt = 0;
        int status;

        signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_hdlr);

        printf("Parent PID %d\n", getpid());

        while (looping)
        {
                switch (fork())
                {
                case 0:
                        _exit(0);
                        break;
                case -1:
                        fprintf(stderr, "Problem with fork(), %d children: %s\n",
                                child_cnt, strerror(errno));
                        looping = 0;
                        break;
                default:
                        ++child_cnt;
                        break;
                }
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Sleeping, forked %d child processes\n", child_cnt);
        fprintf(stderr, "Received %d sigchild\n", sigchld_cnt);
        sleep(10);

        looping = 1;
        do {
                int x = wait(&status);

                if (x != -1)
                        --child_cnt;
                else if (errno != EINTR) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "wait() problem %d children left: \%s\n",
                                child_cnt, strerror(errno));
                        looping = 0;
                }
        } while (looping);

        printf("%d children left, %d SIGCHLD\n", child_cnt, sigchld_cnt);

        return 0;
}
```

It was surprisingly difficult to "collect" all the zombies by calling `wait(2)` enough times.  Also, the number of SIGCHLD signals received is never the same as the number of child processes forked: I believe the linux kernel sometimes sends 1 SIGCHLD for a number of exited child processes.

Anyway, on my Arch linux laptop, I get 16088 child processes forked, and that has to be the number of zombies, as the program doesn't do `wait(2)` system calls in the signal handler.

On my Slackware 12 server, I get 6076 child processes, which closely matches the value of `maxproc  6079`.  My
 user ID has 2 other processes running, `sshd` and Zsh.  Along with the first, non-zombie instance of the program above that makes 6079.

The `fork(2)` system call fails with a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error. I don't see any other evidence of what resource is unavailable.  I do get somewhat different numbers if I run my program simultaneously in 2 different xterms, but they add up to the same number as if I run it in one xterm. I assume it's process table entries, or swap or some system-wide resource, and not just an arbitrary limit.

I don't have anything else running to try it on right now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what HP-UX's limits are. I can tell you however that the logical implementation is to have a process table with a maximum size. The total number of process table entries is theoretically limited by the range of process IDs, but most implementations have a size limit for the table which yields a much smaller maximum. Most unix variants have a per-user limit on the number of processes, too; you can see the limit by running `ulimit -u` in bash.

I don't expect a unix system to have a separate limit on zombies, rather than on the number of process IDs (which includes actual processes as well as zombies). So when a process dies and becomes a zombie, that doesn't affect the limit: the resource (the entry in the process table) is allocated when a process forks and freed when the process is reaped.

Answer (score 2):

*I think you could have any number of zombies just as if you can have any number of processes...?*

A zombie process is finally a process -in a special state- then zombie processes are limited to availability and size of the process table, as for *regular* processes.

*Is it different value from distro to distro?*

Surely, as many other parameters. You should not relay on a specific size, or if it is big enough to hold many zombie process. If you are getting too many zombies the solution is not a big table, because it will became eventually full. A zombie process is not bad by itself, but having too many accumulated zombie processes is an indication of a "badly behaved" program that is allowing such that zombie processes.

*What occurs if we hit the upper limit and try to create another zombie?*

Once the process table is full -of regular and zombie processes-, no new -regular- process can be created, even if the system has enough resources -memory, processor, etc.-. The only lacking resource is just a single entry in the process table. Already running programs -even those "well behaved"- will start to fail when they require to create a sub-process. New programs could not be started, and even running single commands would fail.

Comment: `Even running single commands would fail.` -> that's a big impact.